# css3 Transition delay if animate svg fill and color at the same time bug in chrome works in FF

Tags: svg, css-transitions

i have a link with an inline svg and a text. I want to animate on :hover (or add an .active class), but on Chrome the transition isn't happening at the same time. On Firefox everything is working perfect.

```
* {
  transition: all 1s;
}

path {
  fill: currentColor;
}

a {
  color: #545454;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  
  &:hover {
    color: #4444ff;
  }
}
```

[Here is a demo on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNvgvy)

Is there somebody who knows a solution for this problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess what happens here is the difference between FF and Chrome in the way inherited css is propagated during transition phase. FF does so immediately, while Chrome applies new style value to a child element only when transition on parent is finished.

Take a look at this example: https://jsbin.com/koruyeludi/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output and keep an eye on color values printed in console when you hover.

Example has 2 spans, `.child` is nested within `.parent`. Both have transition applied to them. When you hover over parent span, color is changed gradually. Once transition is done on parent, color is changed on child node. And since it has transition as well it comes into play now.

So in your example you have `* { transition: all 1s; }`. Parent `<a>` will be in color transition during [0s-1s] interval. `<span>` and `<svg>` will be changing their color during [1s-2s]. And `<path>` will be making a change in [2s-3s].
To avoid that, apply `transition:` only once - on root `<a>` element).

Comment: this causes the same delay, but just in 1s: .33s, .33s, .33s

Comment: Apply your transition on the a tag instead on every tag. 

a{transition:0.2s all;}
a *:not(svg):not(path){transition:0.2s all;}